# How do I dispatch cat in R S3?

Tags: r, r-s3

```
> foo <- structure(list(one=1,two=2), class = "foo")

> cat(foo)
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

OK I'll add this to the generic cat:

```
> cat.foo<-function(x){cat(foo$one,foo$two)}
> cat(foo)
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

No dice.

Comment: Just writing a new function with name of the form function.class doesn't do much if the function wasn't generic in the first place.  With that said I haven't tried it yet but I have a feeling the fact that cat has ... as its first parameter might cause some complications

Comment: Is there anything explicitly wrong with calling cat.foo directly? `cat.foo(foo)`

Comment: a shortcut solution is to define `print.foo`.

Comment: ```> print.foo<-function(x){cat(foo$one,foo$two)}
> cat(foo)
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'```

Comment: I think agstudy is implying that you use print instead of cat.  Why do you *need* to use cat for this?  `print` is already generic so it's easy enough to write your own methods for you own classes.

Comment: the whole point of generics is to allow users to reuse the commands they are familiar with

Comment: @JeremyLeipzig except that `cat()` isn't generic, so you generally  wouldn't expect it to behave differently with different inputs

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  `cat()` is not a generic function so you can't write methods for it.

You could make new version of `cat()` that is generic:

```
cat <- function(..., file = "", sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL,
                append = FALSE) {
  UseMethod("cat")
}
cat.default <- function(..., file = "", sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL,
                append = FALSE) {
  base::cat(..., file = file, sep = sep, fill = fill, labels = labels, 
    append = append)
}
```

But the semantics of dispatching on `...`is not well defined (I couldn't find where, if anywhere, it's documented).  It looks like dispatch occurs based only on the first element in `...`:

```
cat.integer <- function(...) "int"
cat.character <- function(...) "chr"
cat(1L)
#> [1] "int"
cat("a")
#> [1] "chr"
```

This means that the class of the second and all subsequent arguments is ignored:

```
cat(1L, "a")
#> [1] "int"
cat("a", 1L)
#> [1] "chr"
```

If you want to add a `foo` method to `cat()`, you just need a little extra checking:

```
cat.foo <- function(..., file = "", sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL,
                    append = FALSE) {
  dots <- list(...)
  if (length(dots) > 1) {
    stop("Can only cat one foo at a time")
  }
  foo <- dots[[1]]
  cat(foo$one, foo$two, file = file, sep = sep, fill = fill, labels = labels, 
    append = append)
  cat("\n")
}
foo <- structure(list(one=1,two=2), class = "foo")
cat(foo)
#> 1 2
```

Comment: I don't think you make a convincing argument here.  Are you trying to say nobody can make their own generic functions? (I know that's not the argument you're trying to make - but it isn't clear why you couldn't define cat to be a generic and have cat.default make a call to base::cat).  I think I actually got it to work but it's a kludge and I don't like it so I'm not posting my workaround as a solution for the time being - but I would like to hear what you have to say on this.

Comment: @Dason well it's important to add methods to `base::cat` because it's not generic. You can of course write your own generic function and call it `cat()`, but the semantics of `...` dispatch are tricky, as I describe in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the example in your post is what you're actually trying to achieve and not just some toy example to explain your point, you could simply redefine `cat` to handle `list`s in the desired way:

```
cat <- function(...) do.call(base::cat, as.list(do.call(c, list(...))))

R> cat(list(1,2))
1 2R> cat(list(1,2), sep=',')
1,2R> cat(c(1,2))
1 2R> cat(c(1,2), sep=',')
1,2R>
```